# Deedle Series.LastValue and Series.tryLastValue both fail if the last value is missing

Tags: f#, deedle

Despite the comments on the code both Series.LastValue and Series.tryLastValue fails if the last value is missing as both functions use the same getAt (series.KeyCount-1).

What is recommended way to get potential missing value from the series?

try Series.LastValue with? or Series.TryGet(key)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the series is ordered, you can do the following:

```
let s = series [1 => 1.0; 2 => nan]
s.Get(s.LastKey(), Lookup.ExactOrSmaller)
```

Here, we want to look for a value for the last key, or the first non-missing value before that.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is not to get the last available value but get the last value (or value at any place of the series) even when it is missing. I know using try with block around the accessor or TryGet with the key than check OptionalValue will work, but I am not sure which is more efficient. I found some of the accessor API didn't honor the the optionalValue design that is intended. They went straight to ````.Value````. Internally Deedle holds all the missing values, you can print, write to csv or db but accessing them individually takes lots of try and true.